# SQL query takes much longer than expected, how to optimize it?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

```
select UPPER(x_col_name)  
from xyz_table  
where x_id = 2;
```

say result from upper query is abc_column

```
WITH ref_data AS (  
SELECT MIN(abc_column_date) ref_date
FROM abc_table
WHERE
    abc_id = 6  
) SELECT abc_column, abc_column_date - ref_date age  
FROM abc_table, ref_data  
WHERE  abc_id = 6
```

The first query takes 0.27 seconds on average while the last one takes over 40 seconds, consider I don't wan't to go with indexing, would there be any other option I am left with?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help, along with an explanation of what you want to do.  It is unclear why your first query on `xyz_table` would have anything at all to do with your second query on `abc_table`.

Comment: Essentially the question you have asked is, "When I drive to the store in my car it takes 15 mins but when I drive into town using my uncle's car it takes 30 mins. Why is that?" Simply, you have provided nearly enough information for us to explain why these two queries have different elapsed times.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT abc_column,
       ( abc_column_date - MIN(abc_column_date) OVER () ) as age
FROM abc_table
WHERE abc_id = 6;
```

And it should be faster.  However, you should not rule out indexes if you are trying to speed up your queries.